# How can i find the number of months between two dates in format 202101 in Hive?

Tags: hive

e.g.

I have date in format 202201, i'd like to find number of months between two dates:
202209 - 202107 <--- how can i do this given my date type is int?

I tried MONTHS_BETWEEN but it requires string in a certain format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('202209', 'yyyyMM'))` to convert to timestamp. And then use `MONTHS_BETWEEN`.
Whole SQL should be like this

```
months_between (
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('202209', 'yyyyMM')), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('202207', 'yyyyMM')))
```

If the column is an INT, you can use cast like below.

```
select months_between(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202209 as STRING), 'yyyyMM')), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202207 as STRING), 'yyyyMM')))
```

Comment: but by values aren't strings, they are ints and i pass it through as a variable

Comment: months_between (
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202209 as STRING), 'yyyyMM')), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202207 as STRING), 'yyyyMM'))
) <-- does not work

Comment: There can be some odd characters. Could you pls use my latest edit. or you can try `select months_between(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202209 as STRING), 'yyyyMM')), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(202207 as STRING), 'yyyyMM')))`